# FFMPEG (swscale) - Is it possible to set the conversion coefficients?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, swscale

Im using `sws_scale` function to convert from YUVA420P to RGBA in my c++ program.
It seems that alpha passed "straight" and does not effect the RGB channels but I do want to pre-multiply alpha.

Is it possible with swscale to set the conversion matrix so I will be able to implement the pre-multiplication?

Comment: You can use the premultiply filter before scaling it.

Comment: have you look at the c code for applying an av_filter :) ? I prefer to write it myself. I was more thinking about performance, it will be faster to convert and pre-multiply in the same pass.

Comment: Looks like alpha channel is just copied without any processing.